# Android Swipe View with Tabs (demo app)

Tags: android, swipe

I try to follow and implement the sample in [Implement Swipe Views](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) but I get error message saying

> Application has stopped

Anyone found a solution for this or maybe can recommend on a good tutorial for swiping view ?

Comment: Do you get the error on your android device? If so, what does your logcat say? There should be a stacktrace there.

Comment: `Application has stopped`!...you should post the logcat error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of examples and tutorials, Just search and try.. I can refer you this --  [Android Tabs Example – With Fragments and ViewPager](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example code with tablayout. Please check this one https://github.com/mehedi-iitdu/DrawerWithSwipeTabs